# jQuery required fields loop. based on CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops

I am trying to figure out a way to loop through the following required fields based on `<input class="required">`. Currently I only am evaluating the first input in the loop. How can I use a loop here to transverse the dom and check all input boxes? Thank you. I have seen similar examples, I just can't seem to get them to work, in my specific case.

```
$("#howMuch").click(function () {
    var numOfPeriods = 0;
    //Validates for empty code only. 
    if ($('.required').val().length == 0) {
        $('.modal').show();
        $('.modal_content').text('Please fill in the Required Fields');
    } else {
        //Clear previous graph
        clearGraph();
        //Adjust the number of periods from years to month
        numOfPeriods = yearToMonthAdj();
        //Declare a variable for the final future value
        var futureValue = createiRateGraphNoInterest(numOfPeriods);
        //Test if were rich
        testFVforMillionaire(futureValue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.each()` to loop inside your element with class `required` 
try this:

```
$('.required').each(function(index){
   if($(this).val().length==0) {
       $('.modal').show();
       $('.modal_content').text('Please fill in the Required Fields');
   } else {
      //Clear previous graph
      clearGraph();
      //Adjust the number of periods from years to month
      numOfPeriods = yearToMonthAdj();
      //Declare a variable for the final future value
      var futureValue = createiRateGraphNoInterest(numOfPeriods);
      //Test if were rich
      testFVforMillionaire(futureValue);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This however, only works if both input boxes are blank. If one of the two input boxes are filled in, that value is allowed to escape the loop and populate the axis of the graph. Do you have any idea of how to fix this issues?

Comment: In order to fix this second issues. I added return false; bellow $('.modal_content') to ensure that once an empty field is found it cancels out of the function

Comment: You can create a var and if some checkbox are blank set var to 0. After all cycle check if the var is different by 0 mean that all checkboxes are filled l. Else meanstthat some checkbox are blank @surgentt

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the elements with .each():

```
$(".required").each( function() {  } );
```